# UIMA Ruta Creating annotation with features separated by some text

Tags: uima, ruta

I have some text with annotations created like the following:

```
wewf.werwfwef. wewfwefwwew. wefewefwff
AnnotationA
asdfawece aefae eafewfaefa aefafe ceaewfae
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
AnnotationB
sadaeceaee aef aewfaegg rresf ceeaefaeaeaf
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
AnnotationA
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
AnnotationB
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
adfcaecae acaeaet aegaegageg caeacdaefa
```

I want to create an annotation with AnnotationA and its closest AnnotationB as features. How should I express this in Ruta?

I have tried the following incorrect way:

```
DECLARE Annotation TargetAnnotation (AnnotationA ana, AnnotationB anb);
Document {-> CREATE(TargetAnnotation, "ana" = AnnotationA, "anb" = AnnotationB)};
```

The rule covers the whole document. What I just want is annotation with AnnotationA and its closest AnnotationB as feature.
Thanks very much for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to specify this in UIMA Ruta and they mainly depend on the offset the created TargetAnnotation should get. The CREATE action uses the span matched by the rule element in order to identify the values for the features.

If the offsets of the created annotation do not really matter, then you can simply use the span combining both annotations AnnotationA and AnnotationB:

```
(AnnotationA # AnnotationB){-> CREATE(TargetAnnotation, "ana" = AnnotationA, "anb" = AnnotationB)};
```

Mind that this rule introduces a sequential dependency between the two annotations. You can also specify rules that do not care, but they will probably return too many matches. It depends on what you want to accomplish.

If the offset of the created annotation should equal one of the provided annotations, e.g., AnnotationA, then you should use GATHER instead of CREATE. GATHER allows one to specify the index of the rule element whose match should be assigned to the feature.

```
 AnnotationA{-> GATHER(TargetAnnotation, "ana" = 1, "anb" = 3)} # AnnotationB;
```

*(I am a developer of UIMA Ruta)*

Comment: @Kluegl I am very sorry that I have made a typo. I know this is TargetAnnotation rather than Annotation. I am also very sorry to say that I havent made my question whole. My need is more complicated but I believe is possible to do. I have already made amendment to my question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer. When I am asked if something is possible to specify in UIMA Ruta, then my answer was almost every time yes. There are other language constructs that allow to specify some quite complex pattern-action combinations. And if something is not possible but useful, then it will normally be implemented soon.

Comment: @Kluegl Really thanks for your answer, which is the correct one. I still have long way to go before I can become adept at Ruta. I have known # notation already but haven't realized that it can also be used like this.