# Position-less GATHER?

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a situation where I would like to combine a set of annotations into one new annotation - using the found annotations as features of the new one. One of the annotations would serve as the boundary for the new annotation. All of the other associated annotations would be within a set number of tokens of the main one. The linked article here is similar to my problem, but I can't rely on positions of annotations; they could be before or after the main annotation AND in any order. This article eludes to a way to handle this scenario: "You can also specify rules that do not care [about position], but they will probably return too many matches." Could someone explain how this would work?

[UIMA Ruta Creating annotation with features separated by some text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605725/uima-ruta-creating-annotation-with-features-separated-by-some-text/24618463#24618463)

Answer (score 0):

So you have defined your boundaries (as annotations) and want to annotate what lies in between, as features for the new annotation (irrespective of the order). Correct me if I got this wrong.

If that's the case, an illustration/solution example would look like:

```
(StartBoundary # EndBoundary){-> CREATE(NewAnnotation, "featureA"=A, "featureB"=B};
```

assuming the annotations `A` and `B` already exist in the isolated span.

The problem occurs when you have more than one annotation of type `A` or/and `B`. In this case, `featureA` or/and `featureB` will be set to the first occurence of `A` or/and `B`.